# Issues with dojo release build

Tags: ant, dojo

We are using dojo 1.7.2 in our application. Even though `AMD` is supported in this version, we are not using that approach at all. We are still going
with the legacy `dojo.require("package")` approach.

We need to create a release build for our application. Below is the profile that we are using to do that. We are using `ANT` task to do this. Our profile
is very simple and doesn't have much dojo require in it.

```
dependencies = {
    layers: [
       {
            name:"cutom_dojo.js",
            resourceName:"custom-dojo",
            dependencies:[
                "dojo.NodeList-traverse",
                "dojo.io.iframe",
                "dojo.date",
                ]
       }
    ],
    prefixes: [
        [ "dijit", "../dijit" ],
        [ "dojox", "../dojox" ]
    ]
}
```

Now we are creating the release build using the below ANT task.

```
<target name="create-dojo-release">
        <echo message="Starting Dojo Release Build " />
        <java fork="true" dir="${shrinksafe.util.path}/buildscripts" classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${shrinksafe.util.path}/shrinksafe/js.jar" />
                <pathelement location="${shrinksafe.util.path}/closureCompiler/compiler.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${shrinksafe.util.path}/shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar" />
                <pathelement path="${java.class.path}" />
            </classpath>
            <arg value="../../dojo/dojo.js"/>
            <arg value="baseUrl=../../dojo"/>
            <arg value="releaseDir=${dojo.release.dir}"/>
            <arg value="load=build"/>
            <arg value="profile=${dojo.profile.file}" />
            <arg value="action=clean,release" />
            <arg value="version=1.7.2" />
            <arg value="releaseName=cutom_dojo" />
            <arg value="cssOptimize=comments" />
            <arg value="copyTests=false" />
        </java>
        <echo message="Dojo Release build successfull." />
    </target>
```

We get a custom_dojo.js file in the dojo folder. We included this JS file in our application. When we open this JS file and search for the packages which are
mentioned in the layer, they are all available there. But when we access the application page, we still see separate HTTP requets send for individual modules even though
`custom_dojo.js` file is included at the top of the page. Could you please suggest us if we are doing this in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be writing your build profile in the old deprecated format. The new (post-V1.6) way would be like this:

```
var profile = (function(){
  return {
    basepath: ".",
    packages: [
      {name: "dojo", location: "./dojo-release-1.7.4-src/dojo"}
    ],
    layers: {
      "dojo/custom_dojo": {include: [
        "dojo/NodeList-traverse",
        "dojo/io/iframe",
        "dojo/date"
      ]}
    }
  };
})();
```

Of course substitute your own paths, etc. Also note I specify module IDs with new slash notation instead of old dotted notation.

I then built it like this:

```
dojo-release-1.7.4-src/util/buildscripts/build.sh --release --profile test.profile.js
```

I have tried this with the above build profile using Dojo 1.7.4 (the latest 1.7 version) and using the following test page it works as expected, without downloading the modules again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="async:0" src="./dojotk/dojo/dojo.js">/*empty*/</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // load the custom layer
      dojo.ready(function() { dojo.require('dojo.custom_dojo') });;

      // to be called on button click
      function myFun() {
        var ifr = dojo.require('dojo.io.iframe');
        // check module has been loaded
        if (ifr) {
          alert('success: '+ifr);
        };
        return false;
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="return myFun();" />
</body>
</html>
```

**References**
It is true that I had to learn this the hard way as documentation is not too easy reading and examples in Dojo sources use a mix of old and new build profile format, which doesn't help either. However those links are very useful.

- http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/build/
- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/build/

Enjoy
 Martin